# "SQLException: ORA-06550" when calling PL/SQL function from Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I want to use Java to retrieve data from database and display it, so I created this PL/SQL function, which returns a cursor:

```
create or replace function std_getInfoFunc return types.cursortype 
as 
    my_cursor    types.cursorType; 
begin 
    open my_cursor FOR
    SELECT s.FirstName, s.LastName, s.Address, s.City, s.Province
        , s.PostalCode, c.CourseName
    FROM Students s, Courses c, StudentAndCourses cs
    Where s.StudentID = cs.StudentID
        AND c.CourseID = cs.CourseID;
    Return my_cursor;
end;
```

In my Java code, I call the function as follows:

```
try{
    CallableStatement cst=connection.prepareCall("{? = call std_getInfoFunc}");
    cst.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    cst.execute();

    res=(ResultSet) cst.getObject(1);

    while(res.next()){
        System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }
}
catch(SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    res.close();
    cst.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

The code produces the following exception:

```
 run:
  java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
   PLS-00905: object SAS.STD_GETINFOFUNC is invalid
  ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
  PL/SQL: Statement ignored

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:202)
at        
  oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1005)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3550)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4710)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1374)
at DBControler.viewStdInfo(DBControler.java:95)
at Test_02.main(Test_02.java:18)
```

Why?

Comment: What exception is thrown?  What line is the error on?

Comment: The eclipse shows this error:                          java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00905: object SAS.STD_GETINFOFUNC is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: If you look at the exception, you will see that it says GetInfoFunc is invalid.  I recommend looking to see if this function exists, and if you are using it correctly

Comment: Yes I created the function before running it. and my function code is on the top of the post, and It seems correct. Please have a look at my function code.

Comment: @SasvathanSarvanandan - One of the table doesn't exist in current schema. Please check the name of tables you have written in the function.

Comment: @AVD-The SQL statement it self displaying the desired output, but only the function doesn't work. In another word, if I rip out the sql statement(select ... from.. where....)and run it, it displays the correct output.

Comment: @Sas - Try to execute "select std_getInfoFunc() from dual" at sql prompt.

Comment: @Sas, you mention in a comment that a requirement of this assignment is to use a function. Is this homework?

Comment: @AVD the code you've posted above doesn't work. "it says function or package is in an invalid state".

Comment: @AdamWenger No this is my project for my co-op work term. I am a college student, and I am currently in my working term.

Comment: @sas - If this function does't execute at sql prompt that means there is **something** wrong in it and I'm sure that the problem is with name of tables or fields.

Comment: @AVD But if the sql statement inside the function itself works fine, so that means the table and fields are okay. isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible causes of error are : (in the snippet - function)

1.
The package "types" doesn't exists.

```
  create or replace package types 
    as 
        type cursorType is ref cursor; 
    end; 
    /
```

2 Invalid SQL select statement (Table or column has been dropped or altered after creating the function).

You need to write a `new function` with `simple` sql statement and run it at `Sql` prompt and with `Java` code.

Comment: yes your right, the package was the problem. Thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Did the function get created without error?  If the type or any tables are missing, the function will be created, but the body of the function will be invalid because it cannot be compiled.

If the function was created without error, and then an object upon which it depends is dropped or altered, the function will be marked invalid and may be recompiled, but then may fail if it cannot be compiled (missing table or column or whatever).

Comment: I checked all the tables and columns, but It doesn't seems like any thing wrong in my table's structure.

Comment: If you go into Toad, it will show you which objects are invalid and why.