# Java: how to execute stored procedure from other schema

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, database-schema, sqlexception

Executing the procedure, **isb.pkg_po_test.get_component**, I have to get a cursor from remote database.

Our schema is **ISBREPORTER** and we have limited access to the schema **ibs**.
However, on Oracle SQL Plus the following is executed very well:

> SQL> var r refcursor
>   SQL> exec isb.pkg_po_test.get_component(15048,6,1,1,to_date('17.12.2017'), :r);
>   SQL> print;

Printed result:

```
    ID PRODUCT_TYPE_ID COMPONENT_ID COMPONENT_NAME                          

     1               1      1012161 some text_1                      
     2               1      1012160 some text_2        
     3               1      1012158 some text_3                               
     4               1        10078 some text_4              
     5               1        10078 some text_5                
     6               1        10040 some text_6                       
     7               1      1012149 some text_7
```

When I try to call it from java code I get this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'ISB.PKG_PO_TEST must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored         

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:210)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:53)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:938)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1075)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3923)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:5617)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1385)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:197)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:197)
```

Here is how I am calling it from java:

```
public void printCursor(PrintWriter out) {
        Connection ktConnection;
        try {
            ktConnection = ConnectionPool.getConnectionKT();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        String statement = "{CALL isb.pkg_po_test.get_component(?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
        try {
            CallableStatement call = ktConnection.prepareCall(statement);
            call.setFloat(1, 15048);
            call.setFloat(2, 6);
            call.setFloat(3, 1);
            call.setInt(4, 1);
            call.setDate(5, Date.valueOf("2017-12-17"));
            call.registerOutParameter(6, OracleTypes.CURSOR);

            call.execute();

            ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) call.getObject(6);

            while (rs.next()) {
                String column = rs.getString("COMPONENT_NAME");
                out.print(column); //to test if it is working
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

> Is it a correct way to execute stored procedure from other schema? If
>   not, could you tell me how to handle it properly?

I have read through other similar questions which were not helpful. Here are some of them:

- [java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: after calling procedure from java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814864/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-06550-after-calling-procedure-from-java-code)
- [java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13: After granting user permission to EXECUTE package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249225/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-06550-line-1-column-13-after-granting-user-permiss)
- [“SQLException: ORA-06550” when calling PL/SQL function from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276139/sqlexception-ora-06550-when-calling-pl-sql-function-from-java)

  ...

Comment: Are you sure you're connect as the same user (and to the same DB!) from your Java connection pool and through SQL\*Plus?

Comment: You were right. In the connection pool I had been using wrong datasource. Thank you so much!